# When div is centered horizontally and vertically, after zooming in, top of div is not visible

Tags: html, css

on my page I have one centered div which holds a form. The div is centered to the middle of screen. After zooming in, the top of the div is not visible, why? How should I fix this? It ignores margin as well.

[image: top of the div is not visible]You can check it live on the test website [here](http://null.8u.cz/).

Thanks!

***EDIT:*** Here's snippet so you don't have to open jsfiddle.

```js
$("body").removeAttr('class');
var register = $("#register-link");
var button = $("button");
register.click(function(){
 $("#nick").stop(true, false).slideToggle({duration: 350, queue: false});
 $("#password-repeat").stop(true, false).slideToggle({duration: 350, queue: false});
 button.html(button.html() == 'Prihlásiť sa' ? "Registrovať sa" : "Prihlásiť sa");
 register.text(register.text() == "alebo sa zaregistruj" ? "alebo sa prihlás" : "alebo sa zaregistruj");

});
```

```css
/* general */
.preload *{-webkit-transition:none !important;-moz-transition:none !important;-ms-transition:none !important;-o-transition:none !important;transition:none !important}

html { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: inherit; box-sizing: inherit; }

a{
  color: white;
}

a:active {
    color: red;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#6a11cb), to(#2575fc));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6a11cb 0%, #2575fc 100%);
  font-size: 1em;
  height: inherit;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: .9em;
  font-family: Pacifico;
  font-size: 5em;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#d93589), to(#c72b5a));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #d93589, #c72b5a);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

form{
  max-width: 19.750em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

form input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

form input:focus{
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}

form input:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

button{
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#ec008c), to(#fc6767));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ec008c, #fc6767);
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2.063em;
  padding: 1.250em 2.500em;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

form small a{
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.popup{
  background: white;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 3.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<body class="preload">
  <div class="popup">
   <h1 class="heartbeat">Lorem.</h1>
   <form>
    <input style="display:none;" type="text" placeholder="Prezývka" id="nick">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Heslo" id="password">
    <input style="display: none;" type="password" placeholder="Heslo znova" id="password-repeat">
    <button type="submit">Prihlásiť sa</button>
    <small><a href="#" id="register-link">alebo sa zaregistruj</a></small>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you post the code instead of your live url?

Comment: @Nitheesh sure.

Comment: @Nitheesh added

Comment: Automatically after a level of zooming the screen will pop out from the screen. In that case, the content will be outside the screen. If you are ok with this you can look at my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I figured out how to fix that. I didn't use `display: flex;` or even `position: absolute;` this time. I used `display:table;` to center the div. The Problem disappeared.

I changed `.popup` to:

```
.popup{
  background: white;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 10%;
}
```

Then I changed body:

```
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#6a11cb), to(#2575fc));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6a11cb 0%, #2575fc 100%);
  font-size: 1em;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And added #center div:

```
#center{
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I changed HTML as well(wrapped content to #center div).

---

You can see bellow a snippet with all the code.

```js
$("body").removeAttr('class');
var register = $("#register-link");
var button = $("button");
register.click(function(){
 $("#nick").stop(true, false).slideToggle({duration: 350, queue: false});
 $("#password-repeat").stop(true, false).slideToggle({duration: 350, queue: false});
 button.html(button.html() == 'Prihlásiť sa' ? "Registrovať sa" : "Prihlásiť sa");
 register.text(register.text() == "alebo sa zaregistruj" ? "alebo sa prihlás" : "alebo sa zaregistruj");

});
```

```css
/* general */
.preload *{-webkit-transition:none !important;-moz-transition:none !important;-ms-transition:none !important;-o-transition:none !important;transition:none !important}

html { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: inherit; box-sizing: inherit;}

a{
  color: white;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
}

html, body {
  height:100%;
}

body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#6a11cb), to(#2575fc));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6a11cb 0%, #2575fc 100%);
  font-size: 1em;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#center{
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: .9em;
  font-family: Pacifico;
  font-size: 5em;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#d93589), to(#c72b5a));
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #d93589, #c72b5a);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 0;
  cursor: default;
}

form{
  max-width: 19.750em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

form input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

form input:focus{
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}

form input:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

button{
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#ec008c), to(#fc6767));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ec008c, #fc6767);
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2.063em;
  padding: 1.250em 2.500em;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

form small a{
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.popup{
  background: white;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 12%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<body class="preload">
  <div id="center">
   <div class="popup">
    <h1 class="heartbeat">Lorem.</h1>
    <form>
     <input style="display:none;" type="text" placeholder="Prezývka" id="nick">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
     <input type="password" placeholder="Heslo" id="password">
     <input style="display: none;" type="password" placeholder="Heslo znova" id="password-repeat">
     <button type="submit">Prihlásiť sa</button>
     <small><a href="#" id="register-link">alebo sa zaregistruj</a></small>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Hope I helped you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

}
```

U can use Media query to adjust as above. I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You used absolute position wrongly use this way:

```
.popup {
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

After that, you must change your input styles. Use media queries for good design.
I suggest you use a responsive framework such as [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/).

You can use this too:

```
<div class="vam-container">
  <div class="vam-item">
  </div>
</div>

/*Should not use with clearfix*/
.vam-container:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*Should not set width property 100% or full width*/
.vam-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I want to center it verticaly too.

Comment: You can do that like here: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: I don't want to use flexbox.

Comment: There is another way too. see this: /*Should not use with clearfix*/
.vam-container:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*Should not set width property 100% or full width*/
.vam-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: Use vam-container for parent and vam-item for the item.

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658141/css-center-form-in-page-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 0):

Set a `max-height: 100vh`to `popup` class

```css
html {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        
        a {
            color: white;
        }
        
        a:active {
            color: red;
        }
        
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#6a11cb), to(#2575fc));
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #6a11cb 0%, #2575fc 100%);
            font-size: 1em;
            height: inherit;
        }
        
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-bottom: .9em;
            font-family: Pacifico;
            font-size: 5em;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#d93589), to(#c72b5a));
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #d93589, #c72b5a);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            margin-top: 0;
            cursor: default;
        }
        
        form {
            max-width: 19.750em;
            margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        form input {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: black;
            border: none;
            padding: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 0.313em;
            outline: none;
            -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
            transition: background 0.5s;
        }
        
        form input:focus {
            background: rgba(black, 1);
        }
        
        form input:last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        
        button {
            margin-top: 1em;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#ec008c), to(#fc6767));
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #ec008c, #fc6767);
            background-size: 200%;
            background-position: left;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 2.063em;
            padding: 1.250em 2.500em;
            max-width: 100%;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;
            margin: 1em auto;
        }
        
        form small a {
            display: block;
            color: black;
        }
        
        .popup {
            background: white;
            border-radius: .5em;
            padding: 3.5%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            max-height: 100vh;
        }
```

```html
<body class="preload">
    <div class="popup">
        <h1 class="heartbeat">Lorem.</h1>
        <form>
            <input style="display:none;" type="text" placeholder="Prezývka" id="nick">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Heslo" id="password">
            <input style="display: none;" type="password" placeholder="Heslo znova" id="password-repeat">
            <button type="submit">Prihlásiť sa</button>
            <small><a href="#" id="register-link">alebo sa zaregistruj</a></small>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So after zooming definitely the content will pop out of div. In that case what should happen?

Comment: Add a scrollbar? @Nitheesh

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following rule, which will apply for all windows whose height is less than 400px (= the appr. height of your popup). It will place the popup in the horizontal center at the top of the window and make it scrollable.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 400px) {
  .popup {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    transform: none;
    width: 396px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Here it is in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g86qnjfk/1/

Comment: Yep, this fixed this, but I would use `position: static;` instead of `position: relative;`

Comment: you need `postion: relative` for the centering with `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Had some issues with this ^. Check out my answer.